# Sequences $a_n = 10^n \mod k$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

define the sequences:

$a_n = 10^n \mod k ,k \in N$

when that sequence contains all natural numbers that less than k?

for example, k=7: $
3,2,6,4,5,1,... $

I found that only when k is a prime the condition holds, but not for all the primes, there is a name for that set of numbers?

Comment: These are so called full reptend primes (or long primes) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\gcd(k,10)=1$, the number of integers represented by such a sequence is just the order of $10$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}_{/k\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$. So every integer in $[1,k-1]$ appears somewhere iff $10$ is a generator for $\left(\mathbb{Z}_{/k\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$. For sure, if $k$ is a prime of the form $20m+1$, that cannot happen: by quadratic reciprocity, in such a case $10$ is a square in $\left(\mathbb{Z}_{/k\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$, hence the order of $10$ is at most $10m$.

Answer (score 3):

This happens precisely when $10$ has order $k-1$ modulo $k$. In particular, it follows that $k$ must be prime. Moreover, $10$ must then be a *primitive root* modulo $k$. [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) asserts that if $n$ is not a square nor $-1$, then $n$ is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes. The conjecture is not resolved for any single $n$ (in particular, it's not known for $10$), but assuming generalized Riemann hypothesis it holds for all $n$.